# What is this insect, is it a butterfly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am not sure if this is the good place: I am wondering what sort of insect is in this picture. It is approximately 10 millimeters long and 15 wide with the wings.

[image]

I have found one of them each day for one week, in my flat, near the coast of France. Tonight I found three of them at the same time. I am wondering if they are dangerous/damaging....

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should also include the species-identification tag (done for you by MattDMo) and an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Looks more like a moth than a butterfly to me